# What's the meaning of "when nothing is happening"?

Tags: meaning

http://www.book-ebooks.com/products/reading-epub/product-id/9586453/title/Irresistible.html?voet=02.03.2017&order=voedatz

The main text: Seventy-seven percent of eighteen- to twenty-four-year-olds claimed that they reached for their phones before doing anything else **when nothing is happening**.

Comment: The same scenario that makes you come and browse EL&U.

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret this as meaning, when not otherwise engaged; where attention is not directed at anything in particular.

Answer (score 0):

It means when there is nothing special/important/urgent to do for those teens.